# Display file name after selecting it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a button on my site that will allow the user to upload a file from their device (computer, phone).

I have already made this button and it opens a window where you can select a file.

But I ran into a problem: I would like to display the name of this file on the page.

I have this component highlighted in orange:

```
   export default function BoxForChoiceFile() {
        return (
            <Card sx={styles.CommonStyle}>
                <SelectFileButton></SelectFileButton>
            </Card>
        );
    }
```

And in the BoxForChoiceFile component there is a button for choosing a file

```
    export default function SelectFileButton() {

    const fileInput = useRef();
    const selectFile = () => {
        fileInput.current.click();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" style={{ "display": "none" }} ref={fileInput} />
            <Button onClick={selectFile} className='btn btn-primary' sx={styles.DispositionBottom}>
                <span>Upload</span>
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what **Alberto Anderick Jr** answered, this is how you can pass the file name from the child component to the father component and show it below **SelectFileComponent**, in your **BoxForChoiceFile** :

```js
export default function BoxForChoiceFile() {
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
    return (
        <div>
            <Card sx={styles.CommonStyle}>
                <SelectFileButton setFileName={setFileName} />
            </Card>
            <h5>{fileName}</h5>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and in your **SelectFileComponent**:

```js
export default function SelectFileButton(props) {
    const {setFileName} = props;
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

    const fileInput = useRef();
    const selectFile = () => {
        fileInput.current.click();
    };

    const updateName = () => {
        setFile(fileInput.current.files[0]);
        setFileName(fileInput.current.files[0]?.name);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" style={{ display: "none" }} ref={fileInput} onChange={updateName} />
            <button onClick={selectFile} className="btn btn-primary">
                <span>Upload</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you can capture the name of the file selected into a state:

```js
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function SelectFileButton() {
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");

  const fileInput = useRef();
  const selectFile = () => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };

  const updateName = () => {
    setFileName(fileInput.current.files[0]?.name);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" style={{ display: "none" }} ref={fileInput} onChange={updateName} />
      <button onClick={selectFile} className="btn btn-primary">
        <span>Upload</span>
      </button>
      <h5>{fileName}</h5>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code can definitely be improved depending on your case, but it should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, that's kind of what I need. But can you tell me how to place {fileName} below the component it's currently in?